# I am using diagram in three.js. I do draw different shape of object. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I using `var shape = new THREE.Shape();`. `moveTo`, `lineTo` using but not full fill diagram and `closePath()` not work that `lineTo`. Please, tell the answer.

Herer my code.

```
var square = new THREE.Shape();
 square.moveTo(startX, startY,0);
 square.lineTo(endX, startY, 0);
 square.lineTo(endX, endY, 0);
 square.lineTo(startX, endY, 0);
 square.lineTo(startX, startY,0);

 var geometry = square.makeGeometry();  
 var square = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
           color: color
        }));

 return square;
```

Comment: Please clarify what part isn't working. Also know that `makeGeometry` is deprecated. See: [`ShapeGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/ShapeGeometry)

Comment: Thank you so much. This square 2D object now full fill diagram.  I have another one dought.

Comment: Here I using quadraticCurveTo. z value depth does not use that time correct diagram set. depth value uses that time collapse my image. why?
         moveTo(startX, startY,0);
         square.lineTo(endX, startY,0);
         square.quadraticCurveTo(endX, endY,endX - (widthLength/2), endY);
         square.quadraticCurveTo(startX, startY - (heightLength),startX, startY);
         var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(square.getPoints());  @TheJim01

Comment: @karthick1870 it's better to create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I used in `makeGeometry` method not full fill my closePath. Now i chaged my code  `var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(display.getPoints());` . This type correctly working full fill of my diagram.

```
    var square = new THREE.Shape();
     square.moveTo(startX, startY,0);
     square.lineTo(endX, startY, 0);
     square.lineTo(endX, endY, 0);
     square.lineTo(startX, endY, 0);
     square.lineTo(startX, startY,0);  // closePath



var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(square.getPoints());    
 var square = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
           color: color
        }));

 return square;
```